# Finding the latest dates in a set of objects

Tags: java, set

I am looking to find the person with the most recent date from a set by comparing the birth Date which is a Date data type. Here is an experiment that I did.

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public Date birth;

    public Person(String name, Date birth) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
    }
}
```

and a Main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        Person p1 = new Person("Bill", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2011-01-01 00:00:00"));
        Person p2 = new Person("Ray", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2014-01-12 00:00:00"));
        Person p3 = new Person("Mike", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2011-01-01 00:00:00"));
        Person p4 = new Person("Kate", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("2001-01-01 00:00:00"));

        Set<Person> s = new HashSet<>();
        s.add(p1);
        s.add(p2);
        s.add(p3);
        s.add(p4);

        Person temp = p1;

        for (Person i : s) {

            if (temp.birth.compareTo(i.birth) < 0) {
                temp = i;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(temp.name + " " + temp.birth);
    }
}
```

It is working ok as it is now, but it does not if I will not equal temp = p1 (example Person temp = null). Is there a
better way to do that without using an extra variable? Maybe with a stream? Thank you

Comment: By the way, the terrible `java.util.Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant`. But given your formatting pattern, which lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, you should be using `LocalDateTime` class as the type of `birth`. Or use `LocalDate` if the date portion is all you care about, not the time-of-day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a stream with a [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html) as follows:

```java
Person person = s.stream()
        .reduce((youngest, current) -> youngest.birth.compareTo(current.birth) < 0 ? current : youngest)
        .orElseThrow();

System.out.println(person.name + " " + person.birth);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution  works just fine and if don't **have to** change it just keep it.

But for educational purposes let's break it down and try to express the same behavior with a stream since you asked for it.
You want to find the latest date... Or in other terms the maximum value of the set. Luckily a java stream exposes such a method `Stream#max(Comparator)`

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" );
Person p1 = new Person( "Bill", dateFormat.parse( "2011-01-01 00:00:00" ) );
Person p2 = new Person( "Ray", dateFormat.parse( "2014-01-12 00:00:00" ) );
Person p3 = new Person( "Mike", dateFormat.parse( "2011-01-01 00:00:00" ) );
Person p4 = new Person( "Kate", dateFormat.parse( "2001-01-01 00:00:00" ) );

Person max = Stream.of( p1, p2, p3, p4 ).max( Comparator.comparing( Person::getDate ) ).orElseThrow();

System.out.println( max ); // Prints Person{name='Ray', date=Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 2014} at least with the toString() method of my dummy class.
```

Comment: For educational purposes the first thing we should do is throw the `SimpleDateFormat` class far away and forget everything about it. It is notoriously troublesome and long outdated.